# Writing Bitmap Image to File

Tags: c, bitmap, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to read in a bitmap image from one file and write it to another just to check that the contents were transferred. However when I run my code, the image doesn't get created into the output file.  Instead, whenever I click on the new file it tells me that the file couldn't be opened. Here is what my header file looks like:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// RGB.h  header file for bitmap BMP definitions
// adapted from <WinGDI.h> 
///To get DIB header struct.   winGDI.h is huge overkill for the needs here


#ifndef RGBH  //don't doubly include this stuff, set a flag when first including
#define RGBH
/* structures for defining DIBs //from WinGDI.h  */
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned int DWORD;
typedef unsigned long int LONG;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
        WORD    bfType;
        DWORD   bfSize;
        WORD    bfReserved1;
        WORD    bfReserved2;
        DWORD   bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER, *PBITMAPFILEHEADER;
typedef PBITMAPFILEHEADER pbfh;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
        DWORD   biSize;                 /* used to get to color table */
        DWORD   biWidth;
        DWORD   biHeight;
        WORD    biPlanes;
        WORD    biBitCount;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER, *PBITMAPINFOHEADER;
typedef BITMAPINFOHEADER pbih;

typedef struct tagRGBTRIPLE {  //from WinGDI.h
        BYTE    b; //rgbtBlue;
        BYTE    g; //rgbtGreen;
        BYTE    r; //rgbtRed;
} pix, *ppix;

#define BYTES_PER_PIX sizeof(pix)

const pix RED = {0,0,255};
const pix GREEN = {0,255,0};
const pix BLUE = {255,0,0};

#endif
////////////////////// End of RGB.h header file ////////////////////////////////
```

And here is the code I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "RGB.h" //header file for Bitmap  

BITMAPFILEHEADER *hp; //var pointer to the header file for bitmap   
BITMAPINFOHEADER *p; //var pointer to the info file for bitmap 

#define SIZE 100
int main(void)
{
    FILE *bp, *op; //var for two file streams 
    char pix[SIZE]; //var for char name of input file
    char out[SIZE]; //var for char name of output file 
    int n; //var to hold different values through out the program 
    unsigned char *bitmapImage; //var to store image data 


    printf("Enter bitmap filename: "); //prompts user to enter filename
    scanf("%s", pix);  //collects filename from user 

    //open filename in read binary mode
    if((bp = fopen(pix, "rb")) == NULL)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         if ((bp = fopen(pix, "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file %s", bp);  //prints if file path wasn't valid 
        getchar();
        exit (1);
    }

    //malloc memory for file header 
    hp = (tagBITMAPFILEHEADER*)malloc(sizeof(tagBITMAPFILEHEADER));

    //reads the bitmap file header
    n = fread(pix, 1,SIZE, bp);

    //read bitmap info header
    fread(bp, sizeof(tagBITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, bp);

    //allocate enough memory for the bitmap image data
    p = (tagBITMAPINFOHEADER*) (pix+14); 
    bitmapImage = (unsigned char*) malloc(p->biSize);

    //verify memory allocation 
    if (!bitmapImage)
    {
        free(bitmapImage);
        fclose(bp);
            puts("Memory allocation not allowed");
            return NULL;
    }

    puts("Input File Statistics: \n");
    printf("File size: %ld bytes",  p->biSize); //prints out total file size
    printf("\nWidth x Height = %ld x %ld",  p->biWidth,  p->biHeight); //prints out dimensions of image 
    printf("\nBits/pixel = %u\n", p->biBitCount);


    printf("\nEnter an output filename for bitmap: "); //prompts user for output file name 
    scanf("%s", out); //collects pathway from user 

    //open output file 
    if((op = fopen(out, "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        puts("Invalid file");
        fclose(op);
        exit (2);
    }




    fclose(op);


    return 0;

}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! O. Helm

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the struct definitions from wingdi?  Unless there's something you haven't posted it's likely your structs are not identical due to packing.  They are forced to 1 byte packing in wingdi.

Comment: My professor gave us the struct definitions to use for us to build our code around. But I will check out the struct definitions from wingdi!

Comment: So, aside from the fact the packing is incorrect and `BITMAPINFOHEADER` is missing a bunch of fields, your use of `fread` is also incorrect.  You read too much the first time, to the wrong place the second, and you read to the same place every time in the loop.  I have a hard time believing that code doesn't crash and that the values you print for width/height/etc. are even close to correct.  My advice is to get the file reading properly and then worry about writing a copy of it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the solution is too easy to see.

Are you using the same "counter" in both for loops? I think that will not work.

Also, in your fread and fwrite, you are probably reading to and writing from the same place. You need to update the pointer of where you are reading to.

The comment for your first fread says "reads the bitmap file header". I am not sure it is doing that correctly.

Check your second fread. It might have a fatal problem. Are you sure you want to read **into** bp? Perhaps it will help you if you use more meaningful names for your variables.

Do you need to write BITMAPFILEHEADER and BITMAPINFOHEADER **out**? Check to ensure you are doing that correctly.

Since this is a class assignment, obviously it is best to not give precise help. I hope this helps enough to make progress. If there is anything more than I hope you can find them by looking closely.